# How to rewirte url to visit file under another folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to rewrite if file after `stylesheets` then read file under specific folder
e.g
if user visit

```
domain1.com/stylesheets/index.css actually read  > domain1.com/app/assets/stylesheets/index.css
```

or 
if visit

```
domain1.com/stylesheets/bundle/index.css read > domain1.com/app/assets/bundle/stylesheets/index.css
```

I tried below code but not work...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com\.localhost\$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/stylesheets/(.*)\.css$ app/assets/stylesheets/$1
#or this rule not work too
RewriteRule ^/stylesheets/$ app/assets/stylesheets/$1


<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/domain1.com"
  ServerName domain1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You need to capture the files in question, otherwise apache does not know what to do :-)

Comment: Are these rules defined in Apache config instead of .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava no, below Virtual host tag in httpd-vhost config

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the HTTP_HOST against the host name (without any further stuff, that is):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com\$ [NC]
```

Second, in order to be able to process the query further, you will need to capture parts of it (in parentheses, that is).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in vhost config or in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?(stylesheets/.+?\.css)$ /app/assets/$1 [L,NC]
```

If using vhost config remember to restart Apache after making this change. This is assuming `app/assets/` path exists as full filesystem path of `/Users/username/Sites/domain1.com/app/assets/`